# How to store multiple numpy 1d arrays with different lengths and print it

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I got several numpy arrays (X, ) from a loop and would like to store them. I know that I could append them to a conventional python list

```
A = []
for i in range(10):
  A.append(some_numpy_array)
```

However, this solution does not look elegant and cannot be parsed to numpy.savetxt.

```
numpy.savetxt("out.txt", A)
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: do you need an ascii file as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a list of arrays

```
In [6]: alist = [np.arange(i) for i in range(3,7)]
In [7]: alist
Out[7]: 
[array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

What's inelegant about that?  You could wrap it in an object array

```
In [8]: arr=np.array(alist)
In [9]: arr
Out[9]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

That loses list methods like `append`, but gains array ones like `reshape`.  And array math has to resort to the python level iteration, the speed equivalent of list comprehensions.  And there's one big gotcha - It all the sublists have the same length, the result is a 2d int array, not an object one.

`savetxt`, given a list, will turn it into an array as I did, and then try to write 'rows'.  `savetxt` is designed to produced CSV output - neat rows and columns with delimiter.  That display doesn't make sense with this list, does it?

```
In [11]: np.savetxt('test.txt',alist,fmt='%s',delimiter=',')
In [12]: cat test.txt
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2 3]
[0 1 2 3 4]
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

This wrote the list/array as a 1d array with general string formatting for each line.  Effectively

```
In [13]: for row in alist:
    ...:     print(row)
    ...:     
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2 3]
[0 1 2 3 4]
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

You could do repeated `savetxt` on an open file, writing one array at a time:

```
In [18]: with open('test.txt','wb') as f:
    ...:     for row in alist:
    ...:         np.savetxt(f, [row], fmt='%5d',delimiter=',')      
In [19]: cat test.txt
    0,    1,    2
    0,    1,    2,    3
    0,    1,    2,    3,    4
    0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5
```

People run into the same issue when trying to write 3d arrays, or other arrays that don't fit the simple 2d numeric array model.  You don't have to use `savetxt` to write text to a file.  Plain Python has sufficient tools for that.

Comment: Very clear reply! One follow-up question, np.savetxt the list-of-array seems to format badly if the array is too long. With the row-by-row method, how can I add some string at the beginning of each line?

Comment: `%s` uses the object's `str()` method, also used by `print`.  For large arrays that produces multiple lines and ellipsis.  To some degree that's controlled with `printoptions`, but ultimately it's designed to give a pretty view of the array, not a complete 'machine-readable' text representation.  Converting the individual arrays `tolist()` might give more satisfactory output.

Comment: How do you intend to use or read this text file?  Most `csv` readers expect regular columns.