# How do I make a grid of empty lists in numpy that 'accepts' appending?

Tags: python, numpy, append, attributeerror

I am trying to use numpy.append but something goes wrong and it just doesn't make sence to me anymore. Can someone explain why I am getting an error?

```
>>> np.array([[], [], []]).shape
(3, 0)

>>> a=[[], [], []]
>>> a[1].append(3)
>>> a
[[], [3], []]

>>> b=np.array(a)
>>> b[0].append(3)
array([[3], [3], []], dtype=object)
```

This is all logical to me, yet when I try the following it stops working.

```
>>> c=np.array((3,0),dtype=object)
>>> c[0].append(3)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

????
>>> np.empty((3,1))[0].append(3)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

>>> np.empty((3,0))[1].append(3)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

>>>np.empty((6,1),dtype=object)[0].append(3)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Solved: [How to create a numpy array of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983053/how-to-create-a-numpy-array-of-lists)

Comment: Stop changing the question out from the people who are providing you with answers.

Comment: If you have a new question, please Ask a new question, instead of editing the same post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just look at the shape; check the dtype, and if object, the nature of the elements

```
In [282]: np.array([[], [], []])
Out[282]: array([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=float64)
```

A 2d array of floats.  `np.array` tries to make a multidimensional array of numbers; it's only when it can't do that it makes an object array.

```
In [283]: b=np.array([[],[3],[]])
In [284]: b
Out[284]: array([[], [3], []], dtype=object)
```

Here the 3 sublists have different size, so it can't make a 2d array; the result is an object array, where the objects are lists, and have the append method.

```
In [286]: c=np.array((3,0), object)
In [287]: c
Out[287]: array([3, 0], dtype=object)
```

This is a (2,) object array; the 2 elements are numbers.  Numbers don't have an append method.

```
In [288]: np.empty((3,1))
Out[288]: 
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
```

A (3,1) array of floats.  No append method for numbers or arrays.

```
In [289]: np.empty((3,0))
Out[289]: array([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=float64)
```

Another 2d array of floats

```
In [290]: np.empty((6,1),object)
Out[290]: 
array([[None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None],
       [None]], dtype=object)
```

2d array of dtype object.  In this case they are initialized to `None`.  Again no append method.

More on making an array of lists

[dimensions of array of arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442652/dimensions-of-array-of-arrays-in-numpy)

and

[How to keep numpy from broadcasting when creating an object array of different shaped arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173540/how-to-keep-numpy-from-broadcasting-when-creating-an-object-array-of-different-s)

---

```
In [305]: d=np.empty((3,),object)
In [306]: d
Out[306]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [307]: d.fill([])
In [308]: d
Out[308]: array([[], [], []], dtype=object)   # array of lists
In [309]: d[0].append([1,2,3])
In [310]: d
Out[310]: array([[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)
```

But oops - those lists are all the same object (pointer) :(   I have to put a different list in each element.  Now I can append to them individually.

```
In [311]: d[...]=[[],[1,2,3],[2]]
In [312]: d
Out[312]: array([[], [1, 2, 3], [2]], dtype=object)
In [313]: d[0].append([2,3])
In [314]: d
Out[314]: array([[[2, 3]], [1, 2, 3], [2]], dtype=object)
```

I think you have to bite the bullet and use a list to initialize an object array of lists.  There isn't a short cut:

```
In [319]: d=np.empty((3,),object)
In [320]: d[...]=[[] for _ in range(3)]
In [321]: d
Out[321]: array([[], [], []], dtype=object)
In [323]: d
Out[323]: array([[], [3], []], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce. Do you have any idea why my last edit appends to all lists?

Comment: For the same reason that `alist=[[]]*3; alist[0].append[1)` does the same thing.  The elements are all the same list object.  An object array, like a list, contains pointers to objects else where in memory.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a rather unusual use case but in fact, it can be very handy to have an (nd)array holding lists in each cell. Imho numpy should allow passing a lambda function to the `fill` method. But to achieve what you want, this is what I do:

```py
m = np.empty((12, 12), dtype=object)
for i in np.ndindex(m.shape): m[i] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, stop updating your question when someone answers it correctly. Accept/upvote an answer and ask a new question when you are ready. SO is a Q&A site that is meant to help future visitors viewing your question, and not just you. Invalidating all the good answers by changing the context completely for your own benefit defeats the purpose of this site, to say the least.

Secondly, `np.array([[], [3], []])` ends up with `dtype=object` because it is a ragged array. `[[], [], []]` and `[[3], [3], [3]]`, having a uniform length in all elements across all dimensions, would produce numerical arrays.

`np.zeros((6,),dtype=object)` produces an empty array of object references (containing NULLs). When you fill it with `[]`, you are filling it with a reference to the *same* python `list` in every element. `numpy` has no knowledge of what object you are passing to `ndarray.fill`, so it does not call the constructor on the `list` type for each element as you seem to be expecting. It just copies the reference that you passed in six times. After that, it should be clear why changing the contents of that one list makes it appear that all the array elements have changed.

Comment: yes `fill` should accept a lamda function and eventually a parameter to stop bradcasting

Comment: @KIC. If you pass in a function (a lambda is just a simplified callable), it will copy the reference to the function. You need a different method from `fill` entirely

Comment: yes with should I mean it doesn't. but it should in the sense of a new feature.

Comment: @KIC. I'm not sure that I agree with that. If you want to do that, you can use `np.empty` and apply.