# How to create or fill an numpy array with another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

How to create an numpy array with shape `[2, 2, 3]`, where the elements at axis 2 is another array, for example `[1, 2, 3]`?

So I would like to do something like this invalid code:

```
a = np.arange(1, 4)
b = np.full((3, 3), a)
```

Resulting in an array like:

```
[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.]]
 [[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 1.  2.  3.]]]
```

Could of course make the loop for filling like, but thought there may be a shortcut:

```
for y in range(b.shape[0]):
    for x in range(b.shape[1]):
        b[y, x, :] = a
```

Comment: Just use the expected shape with `np.full` : `np.full((2,2,3), a)`?

Comment: "where the elements at axis 2 is another array". That should be a `(2,3)` shaped array right? Your suggested `[1,2,3]` is not...

Comment: @TomdeGeus: No, the intention in the example is to make an array shaped `[2, 2, 3]`, or what I call a `[2, 2]` array where the elements are an `[3]` array.

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks, that does it.

Comment: `full` can produce unexpected results if the array is object dtype, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43483663.  There it behaves like `[[]]*4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One is to use [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) in `np.full((2,2,3), a)` as pointed out by Divakar in the comments. Alternatively, you can use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) for this, which allows you to construct an array by repeating an input array a given number of times. To construct your example you could do:

```
import numpy as np

np.tile(np.arange(1, 4), [2, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

If your numpy version is >= 1.10 you can use broadcast_to

```
a = np.arange(1,4)
a.shape = (1,1,3)
b = np.broadcast_to(a,(2,2,3))
```

This produces a view rather than copying so will be quicker for large arrays.
EDIT this looks to be the result you're asking for with your demo.

Comment: The output array is as requested, but I think the syntax is less obvious and easy to remember, compare with the answer from jotasi and Divakar.

Comment: Agreed. To some extent! tile() does some automatic prepending of axes if the dimensions of a are less than the output result (broadcast_to does as well actually) so I put the reshape line in to show how to control the process. You could argue that broadcasting to the shape of the result array is clearer. As I mention the virtue of broadcast_to is that it makes a read only view so is very quick.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Divakar comment, an answer can also be:

```
import numpy as np
np.full([2, 2, 3], np.arange(1, 4))
```

Yet another possibility is:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.empty([2, 2, 3])
b[:] = np.arange(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also using `np.concatenate` or it's wrapper `np.vstack`

```
In [26]: a = np.arange(1,4)

In [27]: np.vstack([a[np.newaxis, :]]*4).reshape(2,2, 3)
Out[27]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])

In [28]: np.concatenate([a[np.newaxis, :]]*4, axis=0).reshape(2,2, 3)
Out[28]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```